# How to execute method onClick?

Tags: android, data-binding

Recently started working with databinding. There was a problem. The onClick method sometimes works, sometimes it doesn't. Tried a lot of solutions, but they don't help. When i click on layout, nothing happens.

Code in activity.

```
private lateinit var viewModel: ProfileViewModel
private lateinit var binding: ActivityProfileBinding
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ProfileViewModel::class.java)
    viewModel.supportFragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_profile)
    binding.apply {
        binding.viewModel = viewModel
        binding.executePendingBindings()
    }
}
```

Code in XML.

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<data>
    <variable name="viewModel" type="com.example.testcoursework.viewModel.ProfileViewModel"/>
</data>
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.activity.ProfileActivity">
    <RelativeLayout
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.changeGender()}" ...>
        <ImageView .../>
        <TextView .../>
        <TextView .../>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Code in ViewModel.

```
fun changeGender()
{
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Click")
    val dialog = ChangeGenderDialog()
    dialog.show(supportFragmentManager, "ChangeGender")
}
```

Tried to rewrite the method like this

```
android:onClick="@{viewModel::changeGender()}
```

It's doesn't work. Set listener from code also doesn't work.

Comment: Try directly using `binding.viewModel = viewModel
        binding.executePendingBindings()` instead of using `apply`

Comment: hm, thank u it's really help. But, i have same syntax in another activity and it works. Surprisingly

Comment: I have added it as Answer. Please accept it so that other can find it helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either directly assign viewModel to binding adapter like below:

```
binding.viewModel = viewModel
binding.executePendingBindings()
```

or rename `viewModel` to `profileViewModel` and assign inside apply.

```
private lateinit var profileViewModel: ProfileViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    profileViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ProfileViewModel::class.java)
    profileViewModel.supportFragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_profile)

    binding.apply {
        viewModel = profileViewModel
        executePendingBindings()
    }
}
```

Actually inside `apply` you assign binding variable `viewModel` to itself. That's why it's not working.